# Domain Services and communication against the database

Tags: domain-driven-design

How do you communicate between a domain service and the database? Do you use a repository the same way it's done from a aggregate root? Or do you put the domain service inside the aggregate root service?

Answer (score 0):

So far my services have used the repositories directly via constructor dependency.

Are you including services in your aggregate root models or does your service layer operate on domain models via method parameters?